# Shiny server.R failed to uploaded libraries

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying now to fix an amazing error. Here`s the header of my server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(Rcpp)
library(RSQLite)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)
library(shinyBS)
library(igraph)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(visNetwork)
```

I expect these libraries to be uploaded when running the application, but instead in 3 cases: visNetowrk, plotly and shinyBS, I`m getting several errors:

```
Error : could not find function "visNetworkOutput"
Error : could not find function "plotlyOutput"
Error : could not find function "bsTooltip"
```

So I need to include these libraries manually by using console:

```
library(plotly); library(visNetwork); library(shinyBS)
```

How to overcome this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a Global.R and load all in library's there then they are definitely visible in the ui and server

Comment: @Berecht, thanks! It is what`ve been looking for!

Answer (score 9):

Particularly for **plotly**, if you want to keep only **ui.R** and **server.R** files instead of adding a Global.R (as @Berecht mentioned), you can add `library(plotly)` to the first line of your **ui.R** file. That worked for me.